# Is there a way to get notified whenever screenshot is taken in android

Tags: android

Is there any way to determine when screenshot is taken in android device. Basically, I have an activity which should show sharing options when user takes a screenshot. Is there any way or flag to determine?

Comment: I hope not, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Nope. Not that I'm aware of. This would (as @CommonsWare states) infringe on end-user privacy. There is also no need to do such a thing either. If your solution requires you to detect when someone takes a screenshot, then re-think your solution.

Comment: heres a discussion on how snapchat detects them http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2geaqv/any_idea_how_snapchat_for_android_does_screenshot/ but it probably wont be helpful for your case

Comment: @LokiSinclair But there's a way to blur the screen using FLAG_SECURE. Isn't there any flag or a hack to notify when screenshot is taken? HOW about using File Observer to determine create Event in screenshots folder?